# Restart game in THREE.js after Pausing

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am making a game. I Pause the game by this code in THREE.js

```
if (keyboard.pressed("E")) {
    animate = false;

 }

if(animate){
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

I want to restart the game after pausing,  by pressing any other key but don't know how?
Kindly help me in this regard.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement some simple jQuery at the document level to simply do this,

```
$("body").on("keypress", function (e) {
    if(!animate) animate = true;
});
```

...thus even if `E` is pressed again, it will unpause.  This is assuming you are constantly checking animate on an interval.  Otherwise, you could explicitly make a call to your animate procedure inside of the `if qualifier`